# Django ORM group by a custom Func

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I'm working with Django and I need to group a model by a custom function.

Okay so the query I want is:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week',"model_table"."date") AS "date" FROM "model_table" GROUP BY "date"
```

Then what I've tried is the following:

```py
class DateTrunc(Aggregate):
    function = 'date_trunc'
    template = "%(function)s('%(date_type)s',%(expressions)s)"
    date_types = ['microsecond', 'millisecond', 'second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'quarter', 'year', 'decade', 'century', 'millenium']

    def __init__(self, date_type, expression, group_by=False, **extra):
        self.must_group_by = group_by  # Name "group_by" is already used.
        if date_type not in self.date_types:
            raise AttributeError('The specified "date_type" is not correct.')
        super().__init__(expression, date_type=date_type, **extra)

    def get_group_by_cols(self):
        if self.must_group_by:
            return [self]
        return super().get_group_by_cols()

In [1]: Model.objects.annotate(date=DateTrunc('week','date',True)).values('date').query.__str__()                                   
Out[1]: 'SELECT date_trunc(\'week\',"model_table"."date") AS "date" FROM "model_table" GROUP BY "model_table"."id", date_trunc(\'week\',"model_table"."date")'
```

Which works find except for the fact that the `GROUP BY` clause also inserts the table unique id. This implies the final result is not grouped at all.

I've been checking the Django code and in the `Query` class there's a function `set_group_by` that is the one that mess it all but i don't really know how to hack it.

Anyway I think the correct way to proceed would be to inherit from `Func` class instead of `Aggregate` but then I can't get Djangot to insert the `GROUP BY` clause in the final SQL.

Any idea how to solve this without hard coding the query using `cursor`, `RawSQL` or whatever other way of directly writing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a way to do it with `Func` although it's just a patch.
So start by making the custom function like:

```py
class DateTrunc(Func):
    function = 'date_trunc'
    template = "%(function)s('%(date_type)s',%(expressions)s)"
    date_types = ['microsecond', 'millisecond', 'second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'quarter', 'year', 'decade', 'century', 'millenium']

    def __init__(self, date_type, expression, **extra):
        if date_type not in self.date_types:
            raise AttributeError('The specified "date_type" is not correct.')
        super().__init__(expression, date_type=date_type, **extra)
```

Then we have a simple custom function and our query can be:

```py
In [7]: Model.objects.annotate(date=DateTrunc('week','date')).values('date').annotate(Avg('parameter')).query.__str__()                                       
Out[7]: 'SELECT date_trunc(\'week\',"model_table"."date") AS "date", AVG("model_table"."parameter") AS "parameter__avg" FROM "model_table" GROUP BY date_trunc(\'week\',"model_table"."date")'
```

In this solution he `parameter` or the aggregation function `Avg` can be any and won't be used. Is just a fix to make Django group by dates as I wanted.